# I want my html page to call php file execute queries and return html content without using Ajax?

Tags: php, html, web, web-deployment-project

I have my `index.html` page from where I want dynamic data to be loaded from a database using php, but I don't know how to call that php file from my html page such that code and queries inside php files get executed and returns the html to the html page.

Answer (score 1):

In `.html` file use ajax, and call the php file in ajax.

```
$.ajax({
    url:"path to php file",
    data:{key:value},// send any data if required to php file
    type: "POST",
    success: function(data){
         alert("php code executed successfully.");
    }
});
```